# Problema com Classes e Variáveis em java

Tags: java, classes

Criei uma classe, Dentro dela peciso chamar alguns métodos mas tem que ser o que for digitado dentro do JTextPanel, alguém sabe como fazer?

Essa é minha classe Escolha:

```
    public class Escolha {
public static String hey; //NAO EXISTE NO CÓDIGO É SO PRA DAR SENTINDO PRO PROXIMO CÓDIGO
    public static void Ola() {  


try {  

    Robot robot = new Robot();  
    robot.delay(5000);  
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);  
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);  
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);    

} catch (AWTException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
}`       

public static void Tchau() {  

    try {  

        Robot robot = new Robot();  
        robot.delay(5000);  
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);  
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);  
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);  
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);  

    } catch (AWTException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}`
```

No meu programa eu tenho um Botão:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Escolha.ola();
}
```

Funciona, Mas queria colocar um JtextField que Qual método vai ser executado
Ex1:(Como está funcionando)

[image: Aqui ele Executa normal o Escolha.ola]

Ex2:(Oque eu quero que ele faça)
Aqui ele Lê o JtextField e executa o Escolha.Ola Porque está Escrito Ola na caixa

[image: Obs:Se tiver escrito Algo além de Ola e Tchau ele não pode executar]

Ex3:(Oque eu quero que ele faça)
Aqui ele Lê o JtextField e executa o Escolha.tchau Porque está Escrito tchau na caixa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma solução seria :

```
String t1 = jTextField1.getText();
if(t1=="Ola")
{
Escolha.ola();
}
if(t1=="tchau")
{
    Escolha.tchau;
}
```

Mas não queria criar Vários if's, não teria uma outra forma?

Comment: `peciso chamar um void ` - chamar um void, o que é isso?

Comment: Cara, Quero uma variavel sei la algo que Por exemplo : Se eu digitar no JtextField -> Olá ele vai executar o public static void Ola()
e se eu digitar : Tchau ele vai executar o public static void Tchau()

Comment: Continuo não entendo, sua explicação está meio vaga. Tente editar com um [mcve], para que o código possa visto funcionando na prática.

Comment: OK , vou fazer isso

Comment: @diegofm , vê se tu entende agora

Comment: A solução já está na pergunta. Se você precisa checar o que é digitado, não tem como fugir de uma comparação lógica, como o if. Teria como fazer com switch, mas não vejo sentido em se utilizar para apenas 2 parametros.

Comment: @diegofm é porque esse programa é só um exemplo, no programa original vou ter que criar mais de 100 Voids como esse Escolha.ola, e Depois vou ter que fazer mais 100 Comparações

Comment: @diegofm , só mais uma dúvida, se meu programa tiver mais de 100 comparações é possível que ele fique lento por causa delas? Ou ainda é bem pouco pra deixar ele lento ?

Comment: Com "voids" você quer dizer métodos sem retorno ne? Porque o nome seria "método", void é somente o tipo de retorno, isso estava confundindo sua pergunta antes de você explicar aqui. Quanto as comparações, se for com switch, terá que fazer 100 cases, ou seja, dará o mesmo trabalho que fazer 100 ifs. Quanto a performance, impossivel dizer, só testando na pratica com uma amostra menor, tipo 10.

Comment: Entendi, Desculpa pelas burrices ai, sou bem iniciante Java , e valeu pela Ajuda/Paciência

Comment: Não se preocupe, são duvidas validas, afinal, todos nós um dia tivemos que aprender do começo :D

Answer (score 0):

Oi. Tem sim.

Criei uma classe para mostrar um exemplo:

`package minhaaplicacao;`

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MinhaClasse {
    public void chamarMensagem(String msg){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }
}

E este é o método que chama o método "chamarMensagem" na classe "MinhaClasse ":

 `public void chamarEsteMetodo(String classe, String metodo){
        try {
            Class minhaClasse = Class.forName(classe);
            Object objDaMinhaClasse = minhaClasse.newInstance();
            Method meuMetodo = objDaMinhaClasse.getClass().getMethod(metodo, String.class);
            meuMetodo.invoke(objDaMinhaClasse,"Minha mensagem");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }`

Com isso, vc pode colocar quantos parâmetros quiser.